# iTunes method SaveArtworkToFile failed, called from AutoHotkey COM object

Tags: com, itunes, autohotkey, itunes-sdk, itunesartwork

I'm trying to extract the artwork file from my iTunes MP3 files using AutoHotkey (v1.1). The script works well until it gets to the SaveArtworkToFile method.

```
objITunesApp := ComObjCreate("iTunes.Application")
objLibrary := objITunesApp.Sources.Item(1)
objPlaylist := objLibrary.Playlists.ItemByName("! iTunesCovers")
objTracks := objPlaylist.Tracks
Loop, % objTracks.Count
{
    objTrack := objTracks.Item(A_Index)
    Loop, % objTrack.Artwork.Count
    {
        objArtwork := objTrack.Artwork.Item(A_Index)
        TrayTip, % "Track Index: " . objTrack.index
            , % "Artwork: " . A_Index . "/" . objTrack.Artwork.Count . "`n"
            . "Format: " . objArtwork.Format  . "`n"
            . "IsDownloadedArtwork: " . objArtwork.IsDownloadedArtwork  . "`n"
            . "Description: " . objArtwork.Description
        strFilePath := objTrack.index . "-" .  A_Index
        if (objArtwork.Format = 1)
            strExtension := "bmp"
        else if (objArtwork.Format = 2)
            strExtension := "jpg"
        else if (objArtwork.Format = 4)
            strExtension := "gif"
        else if (objArtwork.Format = 5)
            strExtension := "png"
        else
            strExtension := ""
        strResult := objArtwork.SaveArtworkToFile(strFilePath . "." . strExtension)
        MsgBox, % strFilePath . "." . strExtension . "`nResult: " . strResult
    }
}
```

I get this error message:

```
---------------------------
SaveArtworkToFile.ahk
---------------------------
Error:  0x8000FFFF - Défaillance irrémédiable

Source:     (null)
Description:    (null)
HelpFile:       (null)
HelpContext:    0

Specifically: SaveArtworkToFile

    Line#
--->    017: strResult := objArtwork.SaveArtworkToFile(strFilePath)
---------------------------
```

I have the same result with bpm and jpg file formats. And strResult returned by SaveArtworkToFile is empty. Should this method be supported by the AHK iTunes.Application COM object?

Thanks and Happy New Year!

Comment: "Catastrophic failure".  It is a self-describing error message, it actually talks about the quality of the error reporting.  The method doesn't return a value, that might have something to do with it.  Use a real programming language that supports early binding to get this kind of code right.

Comment: Thanks for the translation of the error message :-) Since I'm generally happy with AutoHotkey as a programming language, maybe some people from the AHK community will have some input to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Manuell: Oh! Thanks for putting back the doc to my attention. In the

```
Parameters: filePath Full path to the artwork image file.
```

I missed the word "Full". In my script, I was relying on relative path. I just tested it with an absolute path and this work!

Answer (score 0):

Googled it for you: [IITArtwork::SaveArtworkToFile](http://www.joshkunz.com/iTunesControl/interfaceIITArtwork.html#z29_2)

> HRESULT IITArtwork::SaveArtworkToFile (   [in] BSTR   filePath     )
>   Save artwork data to an image file.
>
> The format of the saved data is specified by the artwork's format
>   (JPEG, PNG, or BMP). The directory that contains the file must already
>   exist, it will not be created. If the file already exists, its
>   contents will be replaced.
>
> Parameters: filePath  Full path to the artwork image file.

That method doen't return a value (as Hans said in comment). Try:

```
objArtwork.SaveArtworkToFile(strFilePath . "." . strExtension)
```

Comment: I did'nt need help with Google ;-) I have found this info already. The method should save a file in the current directory. And it does not. Also, according to the doc, this method should return error codes:
     S_OK 
     E_POINTER  filePath is NULL.  
     E_INVALIDARG  filePath is not a valid path.  
     ITUNES_E_OBJECTDELETED  This artwork or the track containing this artwork has been deleted.  
     E_FAIL  An unexpected error occurred.  

I don't see any difference in what you suggest and my original code? Am I missing something? Thanks for your input.

Comment: OK, I see what you meant: using the method without the assignment part. Just got it. But now (as stated in my answer below), this work with and without the assignment.

Comment: @JnLlnd Cool. You should accept you own answer, then (and  upvote mine :-)

Comment: Yes I'll do it tomorrow. New users have to wait some time before accepting their own answer.

Comment: Yep! Should be able to close this question now.